# Rails 3 undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass error while trying create a related object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two models, User and Profile, in one-to-one relation and I am trying to create a new profile for a user if it does not exist yet:

```
user = User.includes(:profile).find( params[:user_id] )

unless user.profile.present?
  user.profile.create
end
```

But I am getting an error: **undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, two things. Firstly, I assume the code is wrong, as that only enters the block if the profile is there (and hence can't create it).

```
if user.profile.blank?
  user.profile.create
end
```

looks like more correct code.

Secondly, when you use a has_one, you don't use .create like you do with has_many. This is because the relation object is directly returned, and not a "proxy" method like a has_many. The equivalent method is create_profile (or create_x where x is the object)

Hence, try the following code:

```
if user.profile.blank?
  user.create_profile
end
```

Comment: oh sorry i meant unless - not if - i created this small example just for stackoverflow...i have a more comples structure in my app.