# undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass when trying to create profile in user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I searched and found this [Rails 3 undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass error while trying create a related object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10368667/692622) but that solution is also giving error - stack level too deep hence asking it on SO.

I have a user model and profile model with belongs_to and has_one relationship.

In my user.rb model I have

```
after_create :create_profile

def create_profile
  self.profile.create
end
```

but this is giving "undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass" at the self.profile.create line. The user is also not getting created nor the profile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`after_create :create_profile` is just enough, not necessary to define `create_profile` method, it's provided by rails.

***Example:***

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one      :profile
  after_create :create_profile
end
```

Comment: thanks it worked, one more thing, user id 10 has profile id 6 but he can also see and edit other profiles like 5,4 etc, how to make sure user can only edit profiles belong to him ?

Comment: EDIT - I used @profile = current_user.profiles.find(params[:id]) but this is giving undefined method profiles error

Comment: It would. Since User has_one profile, @profile = current_user.profile would work.