# generate connected models with the primary at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a model User. Also I have a model User_info. One user has only one record in user_info and every user_info record belongs to only one user. I want when I create a new user an empty record in User_info was created.

user.rb

```
has_one :user_info, :dependent => :destroy
```

user_info.rb

```
belongs_to :user
validates :user_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

user_controller.rb

```
@user = User.new(user_params)
@user.user_info.new <----- the error "undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass"
if @user.save.........
```

the table :users has a column :user_info_id and the table :user_infos has a column :user_id

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here: [Rails 3 undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass error while trying create a related object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368667/rails-3-undefined-method-create-for-nilnilclass-error-while-trying-create-a-r)

> when you use a has_one, you don't use .create like you do with has_many. This is because the relation object is directly returned, and not a "proxy" method like a has_many. The equivalent method is create_profile (or create_x where x is the object)